# Giving each data set a name

Tags: python, list, parsing, loops, output

So I have a code

```
print
latOne = dL[1][3] 
lonOne = dL [1][4] 
x = [calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ) for latTwo, lonTwo in zip(latitude, longitude)]
print x
```

this produces distance values in a list with the output

```
[0.0, 3043.004178666758, 21558.2996208357, 40246.748450913066, 40908.82213277263, 43786.0579097594, 67781.1426515405, 79693.11338661514, 65046.35819797423, 92804.01912347642]
```

Now each distance is based on coordinates from a separate point (which has a defined name) 
i.e

```
Sydney (-20.7, 100) 
Melbourne (-20, 120)
```

so my code takes the distances ok and produces the list of distances. What i want to do is to setup the structure so that the distances print with their associated point names. i.e take the lat and longs from sydney calculate the distance and then have the ouput be

```
Distance to Syndey is output ..., Distance to Melbourne is output, and so on.
```

If u need more of my code to help please let me know.

EDIT:

here is the full script code.

```
import math
import csv
def calculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):


from decimal import Decimal
latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo = [Decimal(x) for x in (latOne, lonOne, latTwo,lonTwo)]
DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
 coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
 alpha = 90 - latTwo
 beta  = 90 - latOne

 cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
 cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
 sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
 sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
 cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

 cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
 cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
 cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
 angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
 distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
 return distance

stations = []
latitude = []
longitude = []
with open('data.csv', 'rU') as input: 
      dL= list(csv.reader(input))
      sL = [row[4] for row in dL[1:]]
      longitude.extend(sL)
      sL1 = [row[3] for row in dL[1:]]
      latitude.extend(sL1)
      sL2 = [row[1] for row in dL[1:]]
      stations.extend (sL2)

data = []
print "Station Coordinates" 
for i in range(0, len(latitude)):
    print str(stations[i]) + "(" + str(latitude[i]) + "," + str(longitude[i]) + ")"
    ab = str(stations[i]) + "(" + str(latitude[i]) + "," + str(longitude[i]) + ")"
    data.append(ab) 

print stations        

print
latOne = dL[1][3] 
lonOne = dL [1][4]
x = [calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ) for latTwo, lonTwo in zip(latitude, longitude)]
print x


print
lessthan, greaterthan = [], []
knowndistance = float(raw_input("Please type your radius"))
for v in x:
 if v <= knowndistance:
    lessthan.append(v)
 else:
    greaterthan.append(v)

print lessthan
print greaterthan
```

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with? it's not clear...I deal a lot with this kind of stuff, but I can't really tell what you need help with...

Comment: could you give an example of how the dL looks ?? it could be as simple as looping through for item in dL and storing the distance and the corresponding city in a dict

Comment: @RyanSaxe well what I want help with is using the code. That gets the distances, I want to print the distances plus the name of the station which the distance belongs to. Is that clearer?

Comment: @looseseal_90 the full code is now attached

Comment: I think I know how to help you, but if you could show what a couple of rows of your csv looks like that would be great. And how do you know what latitudes and longitudes go with the correct stations? (you printing the csv could answer my second question)

Comment: @RyanSaxe can i email you the csv file so you can use the code that way? would that be better than publishing the csv code as i dont know how to publish the csv code?

Comment: just publish an example line, that is all I need

Comment: great, that's all I needed

Comment: @RyanSaxe with regards a dic. Can i compare it to a known value. Say i have known coordinates = (20,100) can i compare the dic to that and write if less than print dic "less than" & if greater than print dic "greater than"

Comment: you mean the distance being less than? also you should comment on my answer and now here

Comment: @RyanSaxe yeah if the distance is less than. Is there a code i can right for that?

Comment: make a new dictionary where they keys are the stations and the items are the distances. Then you can perform the operations you need

Comment: Also, look into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really look into [geopy.distance](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/distance.py) as well as a lot of its other built in capabilities. Yes you already wrote one of their algorithms and such, but it will probably have other things you will find you need.

So you are going to want to use a dictionary here. If you can save the latitude and longitude of a station attached to the station, it will make your life very very easy!

```
points = [[row[3],row[4]] for row in dL]
stations = [row[1] for row in dL]
my_dict = dict(zip(stations,points))
```

now that you have a dictionary you can call your latitudes and longitudes by station name and store it in such a way that you can just recall later. I think that is all you need in order to finish your code. If it is not, please comment so I can edit it accordingly.